# Internet Exploder submitting a null file from hidden iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9

I have a page with a jqGrid. On that grid I've added a custom button to the pager that, when clicked, opens a file browser for the user to upload an excel file. The file input is wrapped in a form and targeted to a hidden iframe.

I know that in Internet explorer, you cannot submit a file using javascript. I'm trying to figure out a way to submit the iframe and actually get the file to pass to the server with a value.

In chrome I'm able to submit it by triggering a click on a submit button I have way off the page on file input change and get the file, but in Internet Exploder it comes back null.

HTML:

```
<form action="/ManagedCatalog/ImportContractsFromExcelFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="">
    <input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" style="position: absolute; z-index: 19999; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;"/>
</form>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width: 0; height: 0; border: 0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

The custom nav button fires this:

```
    function ImportContractsFromExcelFile() {
        $('#uploadedFile').trigger('click');
    }
```

And what I've got to work in Chrome:

```
    $('#uploadedFile').change(function () {
        $('#submitBtn').trigger('click');
    });
```

Any tips, tricks, advice, reviews, or beatings are fully encouraged.
plz help.

Edit:

I'm doing it this way, because the silverlight app my team and I are rewriting acts this way and the client would like to keep this behavior. I may go down a jquery dialog window route and give the user a button to click, but I'd like to try and keep it as similar as possible.

Comment: Well IE has not a stellar tracking record, but calling it Exploder is a bit too far :-)

Comment: @Steve So frustrating having to support it. :(

Comment: If I have to do an ajax upload I will always turn off the ajax for IE9 and earlier - as I see it if you can't be bothered to update your browser then you don't deserve to have nice features